# How to convert this type of for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

for example this kind of for loop in JAVA or C++:

```
int N = 20;
for (i = 1; i < N; i = 3 * i + 1)
```

i will be 1, 4, 13

I can only use while to complete it

```
while i < N:
    i = 3 * i + 1
```

How can write it using another kind of style in python?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: The while loop is the best that I can think of.  What are you actually doing with this?

Comment: If your increment were not `3 * i + 1`, I would suggest looking into `range` but the step argument it accepts expects an integer. You could write your own version though.

Comment: Your for loop is valid in python

Comment: @karthikr but he's asking for the `style in python`, for which that loop is not the typical style regardless of whether it is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop implementation is nothing wrong from Python's perspective. If you want a generalized loop structure to mimic the loop structure of C/C++/Java you can do something similar

```
>>> def loop(init, cond, incr):
    i = init
    while cond(i):
        yield i
        i=incr(i)


>>> list(loop(1, lambda e:e < 20, lambda e:3*e + 1))
[1, 4, 13]
```

Once you create the loop routine, you can use it to create any custom loop format as you desire

```
for i in loop(1, lambda e:e < 20, lambda e:3*e + 1):
    print i
```

Comment: I think what the op wants is the 'Python style `for`', rather than C/Java `for` in Python.

Comment: @Ferguzz: The code is quite readable and maintainable if you know how to read it. The routine is a once of and can be reused for any form of series or loop structure.

Comment: @chenaren: The generator can be consumed by a Python for loop

Comment: This is the closest you can come to a `range` emulator which is what a typical person would need. I, however, disagree with the use of having `cond` be callable. It should be a simple integer. The `incr` argument should be callable though. Regardless, this isn't exactly what the OP is looking for as far as I can tell.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 If cond were an integer, what would that integer represent? Are you saying the condition should be hard coded to be `i < cond`? That would be significantly less general than a C-style for-loop (which can have arbitrary conditions). Most obviously it wouldn't allow you to write loops that count down.

Comment: I think this is overly general. It is probably better to just write the structure out as applied to the situation.

Comment: @sepp2k and OP didn't say he wanted the most general solution, he asked for a conversion of a specific example.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for generators. Do this:

```
def series(i=1):
    while True:
        yield i
        i = 3 * i + 1

from itertools import takewhile
takewhile(lambda x: x < 20, series())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it.  It is more specialized than Abhijit's answer.

```
def timesThreePlusOne(init,limit):
    i = init
    while i < limit:
        yield i
        i = (3 * i) + 1
N = 20
for i in timesThreePlusOne(1,N):
    print i
```